# How can I auto-connect to a WPA2 Enterprise network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, automation, shell-script

I would like my computer to automatically connect to a WPA2-Enterprise network as soon as it boots whenever the network is available, without any action needed by me. The computer already offers to connect, and even remembers the password, but I must still hit 'Enter' to connect. Also, connection does not occur if my login is at the terminal. I would like to automatically connect every time I login, no matter how I do so, unless a more preferred network is available.

What is the best way to do this? I am running Fedora 19. A shell script that can be invoked at the terminal would be preferred. Connecting even if the Gnome-desktop has not launched is a must.

EDIT:

The problem is that I do not know how to connect from a script at all, not where to place the script.

Comment: Did you set the connection as "Available to all users"?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a script to make connection to WPA2-Enterprise and give the execution permition to that file and copy that to /etc/init.d/

Answer (score 0):

after  `/etc/network/interfaces` is setup , use
`ifup`

to start the network.

or:
`/etc/init.d/networking restart`